# How should I be handling my theme version numbering?

Tags: theme-development, git, version-control

Let's say I have a custom-coded theme, and here's the `style.css`:

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme
Theme URI: http://someurl.com
Author: Me
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: Some description
Version: 1.0
```

I already have a good workflow with source-controlling via git, but what I'm wondering is how should I be handling the version number? Do I just manually iterate it every time I make a code change, or is there a best practice to automate the version number in `style.css` every time I make and push a change?

Comment: I don't think this has a right or wrong answer, but most people update the version number when they follow a release cycle. I've yet to find someone who has automated updating the version number in `style.css` and I've been involved with a lot of agencies and wp core stuff

Comment: Are you releasing the theme to users in any way? Do you develop it locally and then deploy it to your site via updates? If you're not doing anything like that then the version number serves no functional purpose, so you should either just not use it, or use it in whatever way makes it most useful to you for tracking the work you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practise to use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) e.g. `1.0.1` `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`

1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible changes,
2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

Don't update the version on every code commit in git (just do it manually), rather on every group of features that are implemented/shipped as a release for the theme. Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree that semantic provides the most meaning to version numbers. But it's also important to note that WordPress doesn't follow semantic strictly. Theme authors can version however they like, but their users won't notice or understand because WP intends to ALWAYS be backwards compatible. 
See here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/about/release-cycle/version-numbering/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to automate the version number in your WordPress theme's style.css file using GitLab CI/CD. Here's an example using a bash script in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

First, you'll need to make sure that your **style.css** file has a comment at the top that looks something like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: Your Theme Name
Version: 1.0.0
[... other info ...]
*/
```

The 'Version' line is where the version number will be updated.

Next, you'll create a GitLab CI/CD pipeline configuration file (.gitlab-ci.yml) if you haven't already. In this file, you'll specify a job that will run every time you push changes to the repository. The job will use a short bash script to update the version number in style.css.

Here's an example of what your **.gitlab-ci.yml** file could look like:

```
update_version:
  script:
    - |
      VERSION=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0`
      sed -i "s/Version: .*/Version: $VERSION/" style.css
  only:
    - master
```

This configuration defines a single job called update_version that runs only on pushes to the master branch. The job runs a bash script that:

Uses `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` to get the latest tag, which it assumes is the version number.
Uses sed to replace the version number in style.css with the latest tag.
Remember, this script assumes that your version numbers are stored as Git tags, and that these tags are only applied to the master branch. If your versioning system or Git workflow is different, you may need to modify the script accordingly.

Also, keep in mind that this script only updates the style.css file in the Git repository. If you need to deploy the updated theme to a live WordPress site, you'll need additional steps in your CI/CD pipeline to handle the deployment.